# Lie group empty boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups

I was looking for a Lie group structure on $D^3$, but I've heard that a Lie group has empty boundary: how can I prove this fact? I've no idea...any reference is also appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Lie group looks locally the same everywhere since left or right multiplication by a group element is a diffeomorphism.